# Mixed type iPhone project(navigation and opengl es)

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, opengl-es, navigationcontroller

I would like to have the menu part of my game a navigation style application, customized as I want. 
Then when the player starts the game it should load the game and run like an opengl es application.

How is this done? is it 2 types of apps joined?

Im thinking keeping all the xib files for the menus etc. but I am not sure how to connect the opengl es part, is the actual graphics of the game, the game itself, running inside a viewcontroller?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple recently released all the videos from WWDC 2010 to registered developers at http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/.  The content is still under NDA so I won't mention specifics, but you may be able to find some relevant info in some of the videos related to game design.